# Row_Number() function count in a union

Tags: sql

I'm looking to union monthly data into a temporary table I created. The temporary table uses `Row_Number()` to count records. I'm doing a time series regression and the count order is extremely important and serves as the `X` value.

I need the count in the added union data to start where base data left off.

I'm hoping to use a derived query count to start the count in the union query.

```
Select Count(*) + 1 from #regression_data
```

Query creating #regression_data

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Depart Year], [Booking Year], [Sorter]) as x,
       CAST([Pax] as INT) as y,*
into #regression_data
from #TBB_Temp
```

Comment: I don't see a `union all` in your question, so I'm a little confused about what is being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add new data into `#regression_data` and keep the `x` column incrementing, you can use:

```
insert into #regression_data (x, . . . )
    select coalesce(rd.max_x, 0) + row_number() over ( . . . ),
           other columns
    from monthly cross join
         (select max(x) as max_x from #regession_data) rd
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure a correct running count, you can nest the UNION queries inside an outer SELECT statement:

```
SELECT <columns>, row_number() over (ORDER BY Ordinal,  ...)
FROM 
(
    SELECT <columns>, 0 as Ordinal
    FROM ... -- First query

    UNION

    SELECT <columns>, 1
    FROM ... -- Additional query

) t
ORDER BY Ordinal, ...
```